# Android SQLite query doesn't return column values

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, persistent-storage

I'm not able to add read data from the following SQLite select query function. I have a table with 3 columns, namely driverID, driversName, driversNo.

It's supposed to return a simple string but alas.

```
public String readDrivers() {
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.PROFILE_TABLE_NAME, necessaryColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor != null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.v("TEST", Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));
    Log.v("TEST", cursor.getColumnName(0));
    Log.v("TEST", cursor.getColumnName(1));
    Log.v("TEST", cursor.getString(0));
    Log.v("TEST", cursor.getString(1));
}

String returnString = cursor.getString(0) + cursor.getString(1);
return returnString;
}
```

Below are the most recent results from LogCat. The two strings results do not show up.

```
08-04 20:27:35.271: V/TEST(25126): 1
08-04 20:27:35.271: V/TEST(25126): driversName
08-04 20:27:35.271: V/TEST(25126): driversNo
```

Comment: Are you sure the columns in fact have values?

Comment: What is `necessaryColumns`? What is the return value of `moveToFirst()`?

Comment: Since 1 record is returned, let me assume that both your columns contain **null** or **empty strings**. I assume **null**, since the `Log.v` **fails** printing.

Comment: Can you add a try and catch block to check if any exception is generated?

Answer (score 1):

Problem with

```
cursor.getString(0)
```

**i thinks it is int value so try cursor.getInt(0)**

There are some ways To get Data From Cursour

```
       public String readDrivers() {
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.PROFILE_TABLE_NAME, necessaryColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.v("TEST", Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));
        Log.v("TEST", cursor.getColumnName(0));
        Log.v("TEST", cursor.getColumnName(1));
        Log.v("TEST", cursor.getString(0));
        Log.v("TEST", cursor.getString(1));
    }

    String returnString = cursor.getString(0) + cursor.getString(1);
    //you suppose to get data from cursor like
   String temp = cursour.getString(cursour.getColumIndex("YOUR_COLUMN_NAME"));
   Log.i(TAG , "Required Data:: "+temp);
    return returnString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **[isNull](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isNull(int))** method to check if the column is null

Since you are getting output for `cursor.getColumnName(0));`, it means the column index 0 exists. So, `cursor.getString(0)` should not be considered an error!

Refer documentation for [**cursor.getString**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)):

It says:

```
The result and whether this method throws an exception when the 
column value is null or the column type is not a string type 
is implementation-defined.
```